# Creating & Printing 2D array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2013, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to created and printed 2D array with some letters (in future I will change values of these arrays):

terrain.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using std::string;

void create_terrain(int size)
{
    string** map;
    map = new string*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        map[i] = new string[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        {
            map[i][j]= "[ ]";
        }
    }
    
}

void print_terrain(int size, string** map)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        {
            std::cout.width(5);
            std::cout << map[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void delete_terrain(int size, string** map)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        delete[] map[i];
    delete[] map;
}
```

class.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

void create_terrain(int);
void print_terrain(int size, string** map);
void delete_terrain(int size, string** map);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   create_terrain(10);
   print_terrain(10, **map);
   //...
   delete_terrain(10, **map);
}
```

Compilator gives me some mistakes:
[image: errors]

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Can I ask why two ** for map?

Comment: I found it there http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/7459/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing something like this instead and get rid of all those crazy pointers and new / deletes.  Your errors though are because you are creating a map var in your create_terrain sub.  Then in main you are trying to use it.  IE its not in main's scope.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using std::string;

using MAP_GRID = vector<vector<string>>;

MAP_GRID create_terrain(int size)
{
    MAP_GRID map;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        map.emplace_back(vector<string>());
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            map[i].emplace_back("[ ]");
        }
    }

    return map;
}

void print_terrain(MAP_GRID map)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map[i].size(); ++j) {
            std::cout.width(5);
            std::cout << map[i][j].c_str();
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    MAP_GRID map = create_terrain(10);
    print_terrain(map);


    std::cout << std::endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First error tells you that `std::string` has no such operator, try to use `c_str()`.
Next two errors are about `map` variable being undefined, modify `create_terrain` so that it returns a pointer to your array.